# D3.js stacked Barchart Error

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I Need your help... why is this Chart not running.. Error in Console (d3.v2.js Zeile 2396):

TypeError: string.substring is not a function

var n = d3_time_numberRe.exec(string.substring(i, i + 2));

Could anybody help me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    p = [20, 50, 30, 20],
    x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w - p[1] - p[3]]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h - p[0] - p[2]]),
    z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["lightpink", "darkgray", "lightblue"]),
    parse = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse,
    format = d3.time.format("%b");

     var data = [
                [
                new Date('1991-01-18T00:00:00'),
                52.380001068115234,
                28.56999969482422,
                10.0
            ],
            [
                new Date('1994-11-17T00:00:00'),
                57.88999938964844,
                21.049999237060547,
                10.0
            ]
            ];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + p[3] + "," + (h - p[2]) + ")");



  // Transpose the data into layers by cause.
  var causes = d3.layout.stack()([data[1], data[2], data[3]].map(function(cause) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: parse(d[0]), y: +d[cause]};
    });
  }));

  // Compute the x-domain (by date) and y-domain (by top).
  x.domain(causes[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(causes[causes.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  // Add a group for each cause.
  var cause = svg.selectAll("g.cause")
      .data(causes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "cause")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

  // Add a rect for each date.
  var rect = cause.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

  // Add a label per date.
  var label = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(x.domain())
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) + x.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(format);

  // Add y-axis rules.
  var rule = svg.selectAll("g.rule")
      .data(y.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + -y(d) + ")"; });

  rule.append("svg:line")
      .attr("x2", w - p[1] - p[3])
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d ? "#fff" : "#000"; })
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d) { return d ? .7 : null; });

  rule.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", w - p[1] - p[3] + 6)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(d3.format(",d"));


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  var causes = d3.layout.stack()([data[1], data[2], data[3]].map(function(cause) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: parse(d[0]), y: +d[cause]};
    });
  }));
```

d[0] is already a date object - new Date('1991-01-18T00:00:00') - and parse is expecting a string.

Instead, pass d[0] directly:

```
return {x: d[0], y: +d[cause]};
```

Sidenote: check out the [debugging tools for chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Most of the error messages you get working with d3 will not give very useful messages (like "TypeError: string.substring is not a function") and being able to look through the stack is extremely helpful.